# WZW model - affine Kac-Moody current algebra from Quantum Group exchange algebra

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, integrable-systems, affine-lie-algebra, wess-zumino-witten

In [`Hidden Quantum Groups Inside Kac-Moody Algebra'](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1104251225), by Alekseev, Faddeev, and Semenov-Tian-Shansky, a relationship between **quantum groups** and **affine Kac-Moody algebras** is shown for the WZW model.

Towards this end, the authors show that a certain **exchange algebra** (that is implied by the quantum group relations) implies the **algebra between a current and local operator** given in equation (45), i.e.,
$$[J_1(x), u_2(y)] = 2~\textrm{ln}(q)Pu_2(y)δ(x-y), $$
where the subscripts '1' and '2' indicate the relevant tensor factor the operators are valued in.
They claim this is a straightforward computation, but I cannot arrive at their result precisely, and am wondering if they have made an error.

My derivation is as follows.

1. They start from the exchange algebra (equation (33))
   $$
   u_1(x)u_2(y)=u_2(y)u_1(x)R(x-y),
   $$
   where $R(x-y)$ is given in (42) as
   $$
   R(x-y)=F_{12}q^{Psign(x-y)}F^{-1}_{21},
   $$
   and essentially encodes two **R-matrices** that satisfy the quantum group relations. Here $P$ is the **permutation operator**, $F_{12}$ is an invertible matrix in $\mathbb{C}\otimes \mathbb{C}$, and $F_{21}=PF_{12}P$.
2. Playing around with the algebra (33), it is easy to arrive at (44), which is equivalent to
   \begin{equation}\tag{1}
   u'_1(x+\epsilon)u_1(x)^{-1}u_2(y+\epsilon)=u'_1(x+\epsilon)u_2(y+\epsilon)R(x-y-\epsilon)^{-1}u_1(x)^{-1}.
   \end{equation}
   I am also able to derive the expansion of $R(x-y-\epsilon)^{-1}$, i.e.,
   $$R(x-y-\epsilon)^{-1}=R(x-y)^{-1}+2 \epsilon \textrm{ ln}(q) F_{21}P F_{12}^{-1}\delta(x-y)+O(\epsilon^2),$$
   where I have used $
   R(x-y)^{-1}=F_{21}q^{-Psign(x-y)}F^{-1}_{12}
   $, $sign (0)=0$ and $\frac{d}{dx}sign(x)=2\delta(x)$. This is equivalent to the expression below (44) since $F_{21}P F_{12}^{-1}=P=F_{12}P F_{21}^{-1}$.
3. Next I expand (1) in $\epsilon$, using equation (36), which is equivalent to
   $$
   u'_1(x+\epsilon)u_1(x)^{-1}=A_1+\epsilon J_1(x) + O(\epsilon^2)
   $$
   (where $A=a I_1$ for some constant $a$, and $J(x)$ is the WZW current), and
   $$
   u_2(y+\epsilon)=u_2(y)+\epsilon u'_2(y)+O(\epsilon^2).
   $$
   I also use
   $$
   u_2(y+\epsilon)u'_1(x+\epsilon)=u'_1(x+\epsilon)u_2(y+\epsilon)R(x-y)^{-1}+u_1(x+\epsilon)u_2(y+\epsilon)
   \frac{d}{dx}R(x-y)^{-1},$$
   (where $\frac{d}{dx}R(x-y)^{-1}=-2\textrm{ln}(q)P\delta(x-y)$) which follows from the exchange algebra relation.
4. Doing so, I arrive at
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   A_1 u_2(y)+\epsilon J_1(x)u_2(y) +\epsilon A_1 u'_2(y)=&u_2(y)A_1+\epsilon u_2'(y)A_1 + \epsilon u_2(y)J_1(x)  \\ & +2\epsilon \textrm{ln}(q) Pu_2(y)\delta(x-y) \\& + 2\epsilon \textrm{ln}(q) Pu_2(y) A_1 \delta(x-y) + O(\epsilon^2),
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   (assuming that $u_1(x+\epsilon)u_1(x)^{-1}=\epsilon I_1 + O(\epsilon^2)$, which is not provided, but seems natural and brings me closest to their answer)
   which implies (by collecting order $\epsilon$ terms) that
   $$
   [J_1(x), u_2(y)] = 2(1+a)~\textrm{ln}(q)Pu_2(y)δ(x-y).
   $$
   This is different from equation (45), as there is a factor of $(1+a)$ on the RHS.

Have I made a mistake, or is there an error in the paper?

Comment: Cross-post at https://mathoverflow.net/q/373579/

Comment: Answered there, see [mathoverflow.net/a/373837](https://mathoverflow.net/a/373837/41291)